# Shopify app/uninstall callback registration issue

Tags: shopify

I have registered app/uninstall topic webhook by sending request to

```
POST https://{shop id}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json

{  
"webhook": {   
     "topic": "app\/uninstalled",   
     "address": "https:\/\/{mydomain}/apps/shopify/uninstall",   
     "format": "json"  
}
}
```

I got standard 201 response with a body containing webhook ID. But when I try to list this webhook directly by calling

```
GET https://{shop id}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks/{id}.json
```

or listing all webhooks

```
GET https://{shop id}.myshopify.com/admin/webhooks.json
```

I am not receiving

```
{
    "errors": "Not Found"
}
```

In first case and an empty array in second. What might be the problem? I am trying that on development store. In a list of webhooks in settings section I cannot see them too.

Comment: did you try to create a webhook manually from within the Shopify admin? Did you also try this in a production store?

Comment: Shopify admin doesn't provide "app/uninstalled" topic when creating webhook. But I tried to create hook for order creation in admin UI. I was then able to list it via API. But only this one ... And I did not try production as I have only development shop available now.

Comment: aha! Right! That's possible because development stores don't allow certain apps to be installed: paid apps, even if they offer a free trial. We can let you try in any of our production stores if you like.

Comment: I was using X-Shopify-Access-Token of a free app to create the webhooks. I have also tried now on newly created trial store, but still same issue.

Comment: If it was a 100% free app, then you are good to test it on a development store. I'm a bit confused then. Just for curiosity, why don't you convert this newly created trial store, into a paid store and try?